# Is there a function on numba to do matrix inversion on GPU?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

My algorithm uses Numba do run a simulation on a GPU, and I need to do a matrix inversion, on CPU I know how to do this with numpy, but the cost of moving the data to the CPU just to do this calculation doesn't worth it.

Actually searching around the net I saw that this might be possible using other libraries (scikit-cuda, cupy, pytorch, among others). But I would like to know if there is how to do this just with Numba or if I'll have to chose another library to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Most NumPy stuff doesn't mix with Numba CUDA ([Numba docs on the little NumPy support in CUDA](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/cudapysupported.html#numpy-support)). The recent [Issue 4726](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4726) echoes the same sentiment and a dev suggests CuPy, where you use CuPy arrays on the GPU and CuPy functions to do the work. They mentioned that CuPy arrays are compatible with (CPU) Numba, but as always, you should verify that for your possible use case. CuPy alone is intended for GPU stuff, so you might end up just using that.

NumPy's functions generally check their argument types for alternative implementations (*dispatching*), and CuPy functions mirror NumPy functions to enable this. For example, `numpy.linalg.inv(myCUPYarray)` will end up calling `cupy.linalg.inv(myCUPYarray)`. This'll help you "duck-type" your code between NumPy arrays and CuPy arrays.

Comment: I see, I have to fix my CuPy package because I think there's some error in the installation, but I think I can do this with PyTorch also.  Anyhow, thanks for the answer